# Passing variable from input form to upload.class.php

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload, blueimp

I'm using trying to implement the blueimp jquery file upload plugin.
My ultimate goal is to have the plug-in target a specific upload folder depending on a URL specified ID

ex) ../plugin_path/index.php?job=13

Then the uploads would go to the folder named "13". Accordingly, ONLY the previously uploaded images for "Job 13" would show up on the upload page.

My problem is that after requesting the value from the URL:

```
$jobid=$_REQUEST['job'];
```

I can't get the $jobid variable passed to 'upload.class.php' to reference it in the 'upload_dir'.

Does anybody know how this could be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see more code.  How is upload.class.php used? If it is an included class, the superglobal `$_REQUEST` should be available. (you should be using `$_GET` explicitly, not `$_REQUEST`)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at that plugin, you can do it by replacing the following **Line 39** on `upload.class.php` :

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
```

for the following one:

```
'upload_dir' => isset($_REQUEST['job']) ? $_REQUEST['job'].'/' : dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it SHOULD work, however it is still default to the "files" folder. It seems like $_REQUEST['job'] is NOT set. Does it matter that 'job' is being set in the url of form, not the upload.class.php?

Comment: can you post the javascript where you do the file upload?

Comment: There are quite a few javascripts in this plug-in, I'm not sure which one to post. The main JS application? The jquery.fileupload.js? 
The plugin also states the following: 
"The easiest way to submit additional form data is by adding additional input fields to the upload form.
By default, the plugin calls jQuery's serializeArray method on the upload form to gather additional form data for all input fields (including hidden fields).
The value of these form fields will be sent to the server along with the selected files."

Could this be used to pass the job ID?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've taken the time to look into this and test it, forget my other answer, just edit `server/php/index.php` on your plugin folder and replace the following line:

```
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

for this code:

```
$option = null;
if (isset($_REQUEST['job'])) {
   if (substr($_REQUEST['job'],-1)!= '/') {
      $_REQUEST['job'] .= '/';
   }
   $dir = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/'.$_REQUEST['job'];
   if (!file_exists($dir)) {
      mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
   }
   $option = array('upload_dir' => $dir);
}

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($option);
```

With this change, your files will be correctly uploaded to the folder you specified in the input hidden of the index.html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="job" value="7">
```

There are things to improve, because when you refresh the page only the files on the root upload folder are shown, you need to do further modifications if you want it to show also the files on the subfolders specified via 'job' param.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. Bad news however...after making the changes, I'm getting an "Error - Internal Server Error" on every upload. I'm making no changes to the upload.class.php - that is just stock as I downloaded it from the plugin.